# Get index value for specific positions in a boolean array in F#

Tags: f#

I have an array that contains only `0` and `1`. Lets call this array `numbers`. The `numbers` look something like this:

```
val it : int [] =
  [|1; 1; 1; 1; 0; 1; 0; 1; 0; 0; 0; 1; 0; 1; 0; 0; 0; 1; 0; 1; 0; 0; 0; 1; 0;
   0; 0; 0; 0; 1; 0; 1; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 1; 0; 0; 0; 1; 0; 1; 0; 0; 0; 1; 0; 0;
   0; 0; 0; 1; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 1; 0; 1; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 1; 0; 0; 0; 1; 0; 1; 0;
   0; 0; 0; 0; 1; 0; 0; 0; 1; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 1; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 1; 0; 0;
   ...|]
```

I want to retrieve the value of the indices where `1` occurs. For example, in the above array, indices `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `5` and so on has `1`. I want an array that'll look like this: `[| 0; 1; 2; 3; 5; ... |]`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[| 1; 0; 1; 1; 0 |]
|> Array.indexed
|> Array.choose (function (i, n) when n = 1 -> Some i | _ -> None)
// 0; 2; 3
```

Answer (score 1):

This works, though I'm still a rookie in F# and I'm interested if there is a more elegant solution

```ml
[| 1; 1; 0; 1; 0; 1 |]
|> Array.indexed
|> Array.filter (fun tuple -> snd tuple = 1)
|> Array.map fst
|> printf "%A"  

(* prints: [|0; 1; 3; 5|] *)
```

Explanations:

- Expand the the array elements to get an array of tuples `(index, value)`
- filter out elements that don't match the condition on the value,
- Then take only the first part of each tuple (the index)

You can also turn this into a more general helper function, usable with any condition ("predicate"):

```ml
let findAllIndices predicate =
    Array.indexed
    >> Array.filter (snd >> predicate)
    >> Array.map fst

[| 1; 1; 0; 1; 0; 1 |]
|> findAllIndices (fun x -> x = 1)
|> printf "%A"
```

Comment: Use Array.indexed instead of the Array.mapi

Comment: @BentTranberg indeed, I missed this one, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

System.Linq version

```
open System.Linq

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let it : int [] = [|1; 1; 1; 1; 0; 1;|]

    let values = it.Select(fun n i -> if n = 1 then i else -1).Where(fun i -> i >= 0).ToList();
    
    for v in values do
        printf "%A " v

    0
```